# Individually wrapped frozen steaks have thawed over 18 hours - are they safe?

Tags: food-safety, steak, frozen, thawing

I bought individually wrapped steaks from Walmart, and I accidentally left them out of the freezer for about 18 hours. I don't know if they had completely thawed or not. I didn't 
open the box to look.

[image]

[image]

I didn't have time to cook them, so I put them into the freezer.

They are frozen now... but are they safe to eat?

---

EDIT:

I recieved a response from Black River themselves asking the same question. Their official response was:

> Thank you for your email I received regarding a recent purchase you
>   made. I have spoken to my product and development team and they
>   suggest for you not to consume that product. Having the product out
>   for 16 hours not refrigerated isn’t a good thing so we wouldn’t
>   recommend for you to consume it.
>
> Having said that you also stated that you re froze the product which
>   isn’t a good thing to do since the product thawed.
>
> We believe 8
>   hours would be sufficient enough to thaw this product so we don’t
>   recommend you consuming this product.
>
> I hope I was able to answer your question. If for any reason you have any further
>   questions/concerns please feel free to contact me as I am willing to
>   assist you with any information you may need.
>
> Black River Angus Ltd
>   1-888-422-9656

Comment: MY questions is more about whether the individual vacuum packaging would keep them safe from bacteria.

Comment: The bacteria that can spoil the food are already in the package. What only matters is the amount of the bacteria which is determined by time and temperature.

Comment: Yup, that proposed duplicate applies just as well to your steaks.

Comment: Just to back what has already been said by @Jefromi and Ching Chong, I received an official response by the Black River company themselves which agrees to toss them. I added it to the question above.